# Can't Access Android Internal Files

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to use this method here:

```
NavigationalMap map = MapLoader.loadMap ( getFilesDir( ) ,
            "Lab-room-peninsula.svg");
    mv.setMap( map );
```

What its supposed to do is take in a file directory as object and a string. The thing is, I'm running this on a nexus 7, and I can't save Lab-room-peninsula.svg to my application private files because I can't find those private files, even when I connect it to my computer. How do I parse into this method a directory as a file object from a directory that I know exists in my internal storage of my nexus 7?

Comment: what's your directory path... it should be something like /data/data/%package%name/...

Comment: "I can't find those private files, even when I connect it to my computer" -- users (and developers) cannot access internal storage on production hardware, except perhaps on rooted devices. You *can* access internal storage on the emulator, and you can access external storage on production hardware.

Comment: Nexus 7\Internal storage\Android\data\mapfiles

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't have external storage on nexus7. I have internal storage, any way for me to access that for this method

Comment: "I don't have external storage on nexus7" -- yes, you do. However, you are probably using different terminology than what the SDK documentation does. I have written some blog posts to help clear up the confusion as to what [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) mean to SDK developers.

Comment: Is your file already created?

Comment: Yes my file is already created. so i'm now trying getExternalFilesDir(null), which is accessing the directory storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packageName/files    I can't find this directory manually to save the svg file into it

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments, I think you need to store svg file in private directory of Android. Here how I would have done...

```
String folderName = "Maps"; //e.g.

File folder = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + folderName);
// This would create the folder if does not exist
boolean isSuccessFul = folder.mkdirs();

String fileName = "Lab-room-peninsula.svg";

File file = new File(folder, fileName);
// Do whatever you like to do with file
if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
```